# Highlighted Content for "Approval Status" or Custom View based on 'Grouped by Approval Status'

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, approval, highlighted-content-web-part

How would I go about displaying documents across 10 document libraries on a site when the documents "Approval Status" is set to "Pending"?

I have created a view on each library which can show this data, but I would like to display all data on one page if possible. Either all items in one list, or multiple lists for each of the document libraries on the site.

Is this achievable using a query within a Highlighted Content web part?

[image: Image of Column Name / Properties]

Comment: Is this SharePoint default "Approval Status" column?

Comment: @GaneshSanap - Yes this is the default column.